# Inherited class calls initialization code in base class

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, delegates

I am interested in hearing your opinion on the approach I have taken to have inherited classes initialize their base class.

Here's a Machines collection class from that maintains a list of Machine objects. Each Machine needs to be able to inform its parent, using a delegate, of something they do but they do not have a reference to the parent:

```
Public Delegate Sub MachineDelegate(ByRef item As Machine)

Public MustInherit Class Machines

    Private _items As New List(Of Machine)

    Public Function Create() As Machine
        Dim item As Machine = CreateItem()
        _items.Add(item)
        PostCreationHandler(item)
        Return item
    End Function

    ' Create derived object
    Public MustOverride Function CreateItem() As Machine

    Public Sub ChildMachineDidSomething(ByRef item As Machine)
        ' Handle child object event
        Debug.Print("Machine did something")
    End Sub

    ' Called once object has been created
    Protected Overridable Sub PostCreationHandler(ByRef item As Machine)
        item.MachineDelegate = AddressOf ChildMachineDidSomething
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Machine
    Public MachineDelegate As MachineDelegate

    Public Sub DoMachineThing()
        If Not MachineDelegate Is Nothing Then MachineDelegate(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The child objects will use a `MachineDelegate` to inform their parent, passing themselves as a reference.

Inherited Cars and Car classes would look like this and have their own delegate to handle Car-related notifications:

```
Public Delegate Sub CarDelegate(ByRef item As Car)

Public Class Cars
    Inherits Machines

    ' Create derived object
    Public Overrides Function CreateItem() As Machine
        Dim item As Car = New Car
        CreateItem = item
    End Function

    Public Sub ChildCarDidSomething(ByRef item As Car)
        ' Handle child object event
        Debug.Print("Car did something")
    End Sub

    ' Called once object has been created
    Protected Overrides Sub PostCreationHandler(ByRef item As Machine)
        Dim car As Car = item

        MyBase.PostCreationHandler(item)

        car.CarDelegate = AddressOf ChildCarDidSomething

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Car
    Inherits Machine

    Public CarDelegate As CarDelegate

    Public Sub DoCarThing()
        If Not CarDelegate Is Nothing Then CarDelegate(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I create an overridable `PostCreationHandler` where object-specific initialization is to be handled once an object is created and I am using `MyBase.PostCreationHandler` to make sure the object gets properly initialized at every level in the inheritance chain.

My goal is to avoid giving child objects a reference to their parent.

My question is is this OK and is there a better approach to doing this?